# How to check if a Blob is a real file or a symbolic link used in azure blob storage to create a 'virtual' directory?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to write Java code to make use of the azure storage java sdk to download all files, folders and sub folders with a given directory.

The issue is that because blob storage isn't a real file system it creates these 0 byte files for every directory you create, as seen below.

[image]

I was just checking to see if the file size was 0 bytes and if so skipping, but I need to change it to allow 0 byte files, but obviously to skip over these 'virtual' files.

The thing is I can't find anyway to differentiate between real 0 byte files and these 'virtual' 0 byte files, which really are just pointers to the directory.

If anyone knows anything about this, or can point in me in a direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
if (item instanceof CloudBlockBlob) {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob) item;
            if (blob.getProperties().getLength() <= 0) {
                // blob creates empty block blobs for every directory as it's not a true filesystem
            }
            // is a file
```

Comment: Try using the ADLSgen2 SDK instead: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-file-datalake/12.0.0-preview.6/index.html

Comment: How are you uploading the files? I believe the software you're using (assuming you're using a software) is creating these zero byte files in order to persist the folders.

Comment: Yes I'm using jupyterhub, it creates these zero byte files to persist the folders.